# Use async pipe in other async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I would like to use an async pipe in an angular template with another async pipe in it.

The problem is that my second async pipe return `null`, so nothing is print. But my first async pipe works really well.

So how could i do to print my `zone.title` in my html template ? I can only get it with the `doSomething(id)` methode.

**template.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let site of sites$ | async">
  <p>{{site.title}}</p>
  <div *ngIf="doSomething(site.id) | async as zone">
     <p>{{zone?.title}}<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**template.component.ts**

```js
public sites$: Observable<{id: string, title: string}[]>;

constructor(private siteService: SiteService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sites$ = this.siteService.getSites();
}

doSomething(id: string): Observable<{id: string, title: string}> {
  return this.siteService.getZoneById(id);
}
```

**site.service.ts**

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getSites(): Observable<{id: string, title: string}[]> {
  this.http.get(...);
}

getZoneById(id: string): Observable<{id: string, title: string}> {
  this.http.get(...);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling functions in template is usually not a very good idea as it leads to unpredictable results.

So you can refactor your code:

**template.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let site of sites$ | async">
  <p>{{site.title}}</p>
  <div *ngIf="site.zone$ | async as zone">
     <p>{{zone?.title}}<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**template.component.ts**

```js
public sites$: Observable<{
  id: string,
  title: string,
  zone$: Observable<{id: string, title: string}>
}[]>;

constructor(private siteService: SiteService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sites$ = this.siteService.getSites().pipe(
    map((sites) => {
      return sites.map(site => {
        return {
          id: site.id,
          title: site.title,
          zone$: this.doSomething(site.id),
        };
      })
    })
  );
}

doSomething(id: string): Observable<{id: string, title: string}> {
  return this.siteService.getZoneById(id);
}
```

Check my [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8jawb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thank you, so you recommand me to create in my ts a new format of data and use it. Thats good to know !